# Sending commands to an IoT device via REST and IoT Central

Tags: rest, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

Microsoft describes very well how to send a command to an IoT device using a REST call. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods)

This also works as described with an IoT Hub.

In the Microsoft example, a command is sent via

`az iot hub generate-sas-token -n <iothubName> --du <duration>`

a corresponding SAS token is generated. Unfortunately, this does not work with IoT Central, as the host name of the IoT Hub on which it is based is not known.

I have now been able to determine the IoT Hub via the DPS and have also generated a corresponding SAS token for my device. With this, it is also possible to send data to the device.

In the Microsoft example, however, the SAS token looks different:

```
  https://<iothubName>.azure-devices.net/twins/<deviceId>/methods?api-version=2021-04-12\
  -H 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=iothubname.azure-devices.net&sig=x&se=x&skn=iothubowner' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    }, "methodName": "reboot",
    "responseTimeoutInSeconds": 200,
    "payload": {
        "input1": "someInput",
        "input2": "anotherInput"
    }
}'
```

If I compare this with my SAS tokens, I notice that they are completely different. What is the reason for this and where can I get the SAS token with which I can initiate commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure IoT Central didn't allow full REST APIs access to the underlying IoT Hub, just only for sending an event (telemetry data).

You should use the Azure IoT Central REST [Devices - Run Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/2022-07-31dataplane/devices/run-command?tabs=HTTP) for that. For Authorization header can be used the IoT Central *ApiToken*.

Note, that this *Run Command* also can be used for sending a C2D message to the device via the IoT Central based on the device model, see the [Offline commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-telemetry-properties-commands#offline-commands).

Comment: There's a more detailed description of how to call commands using the IoT Central REST API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-central/core/howto-control-devices-with-rest-api#call-commands. The article also includes a link to a Postman file with working examples.

Comment: Hello Roman and hello Dominic,
Thank you for your valuable help. That answers my question exactly.
Many thanks